# Is there any way to query the Google "My Maps" to get places (in JSON)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to query google "My Maps" so I can get all the places inside my polygon as well as sorted according to distance from a particular point?
I know this type of question have been asked already but I found no solution so I have asked again.
**Edit:** There seems to be 2 different worlds:
1st of Google MyMaps with KML support and 
2nd of Google Maps API which load and query KML from external websites.
Is there any way to query these maps with the js api? I basically want to use "My Maps" as a console where a non-programmer can plot points,polygons etc. and an api which could fetch those points.

Comment: You need the goolge places api, google that and you will find what you need.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  I don't know of any way to export data from MyMaps other than as KML, you could process that to for points in a polygon and sort them by distance from a point.

Comment: Yeah, I too think I would have to parse the KML file and extract the polygons as well as points. What I was asking for an API where google did all these things and would have returned me the results.

Comment: @BasvanStein But the My Maps gives us the functionality where a non programmer can plot points via mouse, does places api give that avantage?

Comment: @BasvanStein Please see my edit.

Comment: Ah I am sorry, I misunderstood your question. I once made something similar but I used the google maps api to store the points that a user draws directly in the database using eventhandlers, I need to search the code though and not sure if it is useful here.